# Optimizing for a certain simple query

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres database with a 80k records, each with a date, key and a value. There are 10k unique keys. Max number of dates per key is 2k. The only query I plan to do is retrieve all the records of a given key ordered by date. I also plan to batch insert new records daily. The records are never altered.

First, how do I speed up my one query? Should I order the table by key and date and then have an index on the key column?

Second, is there a better alternative to Postgres for this?

Comment: How many unique keys are expected? How many different dates with the given key will be there?

Comment: Create an index on "key" and date. 80k rows is actually quite small these days. And database will be able to cope with that. Postgres is a good choice.

Comment: Updated the question with the requested info. Are you suggesting a single index on two columns? Order of the table doesn't matter?

Comment: I suspect that, yes, @a_horse_with_no_name meant a single index on (keycol, datecol). If not, I'll recommend that. Actually, I might go further and suggest (if you're running postgres 11 or later) `CREATE INDEX ON tablename (keycol, datecol) INCLUDE (valuecol)`, which will allow the query planner to skip checking the table at all.